# Shiny and twitter example

Tags: r, twitter, shiny, word-cloud

I'm trying to run a example to process tweets in R with Shiny. I'm using the example in [this](https://hernanresnizky.com/2013/02/21/social-media-monitoring-tools-in-r-with-just-a-few-lines/) page, but I'm not getting any output.

The code that I'm using is as follows (which I've corrected from the page as it had some errors with parenthesis, inverted comas, etc.):

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  # Application title
  headerPanel('Tweets hunter'),
  sidebarPanel( textInput('term', 'Enter a term', ''),
                numericInput('cant', 'Select a number of tweets',1,0,200),
                radioButtons('lang','Select the language',c(
                  'English'='en',
                  'Castellano'='es',
                  'Deutsch'='de')),
                submitButton(text='Run')),
  mainPanel(
    h4('Last 5 Tweets'),
    tableOutput('table'),
    plotOutput('wordcl'))
))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
shinyServer(function (input, output) {
  rawData <- reactive(function(){
    tweets <- searchTwitter(input$term, n=input$cant,lang=input$lang)
    twListToDF(tweets)
  })
  output$table <- reactiveTable(function () {
    head(rawData()[1],n=5)
  })
  output$wordcl<- reactivePlot(function(){
    tw.text<-enc2native(rawData()$text,
                        tw.text <- tolower(tw.text),
                        tw.text <- removeWords(tw.text,c(stopwords(input$lang),'rt')),
                        tw.text <- removePunctuation(tw.text,TRUE),
                        tw.text <-unlist(strsplit(tw.text,' ')),
                        word<- sort(table(tw.text),TRUE),
                        wordc<-head(word,n=15),
                        wordcloud(names(wordc),wordc,random.color=TRUE,colors=rainbow(10),scale=c(15,2))
    )
  })
})
```

I've edited the code of the server.r file as some of the commands are deprecated as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
shinyServer(function (input, output) {
  rawData <- reactive(function(){
    tweets <- searchTwitter(input$term, n=input$cant,lang=input$lang)
    twListToDF(tweets)
  })
  #output$table <- reactiveTable(function () {
  #  head(rawData()[1],n=5)
  #})
  output$filetable <- renderTable( 
    { if (is.null(input$files)) { # User has not uploaded a file yet 
      return(NULL) } 
      head(rawData()[1],n=5) })

  #http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderPlot.html
  #  output$wordcl<- reactivePlot(function(){
  #  tw.text<-enc2native(rawData()$text,
  #                      tw.text <- tolower(tw.text),
  #                      tw.text <- removeWords(tw.text,c(stopwords(input$lang),'rt')),
  #                      tw.text <- removePunctuation(tw.text,TRUE),
  #                      tw.text <-unlist(strsplit(tw.text,' ')),
  #                      word<- sort(table(tw.text),TRUE),
  #                      wordc<-head(word,n=15),
  #                      wordcloud(names(wordc),wordc,random.color=TRUE,colors=rainbow(10),scale=c(15,2))
  #  )
  #})

  output$wordcl<- renderPlot(
      function(){
        tw.text<-enc2native(rawData()$text)
                            tw.text <- tolower(tw.text)
                            tw.text <- removeWords(tw.text,c(stopwords(input$lang),'rt'))
                            tw.text <- removePunctuation(tw.text,TRUE)
                            tw.text <-unlist(strsplit(tw.text,' '))
                            word<- sort(table(tw.text),TRUE)
                            wordc<-head(word,n=15)
                            wordcloud(names(wordc),wordc,random.color=TRUE,colors=rainbow(10),scale=c(15,2))
      }
                            ,width = "auto", height = "auto", res = 72, 
               env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE, execOnResize = FALSE,
               outputArgs = list())

})
```

But I'm not getting any output

Any ideas what is causing I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to trace the source of error?, i.e. to check the reactive values and print them, or add print("here") at certain locations?
How did you start your investigation?

Comment: I've corrected some deprecated commands (I'll edit to show the code), but now I'm getting another error

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work. Here is the code. I hope it can help someone

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
shinyServer(function (input, output) {
  rawData <- reactive(
    { tweets <- searchTwitter(input$term, n=input$cant,lang=input$lang)
    return(twListToDF(tweets))
  })

  output$tablel <- renderTable( {
      head(rawData()[1],n=5)
    })

  output$wordcl<- renderPlot(
      {
        tw.text <- rawData()$text
        tw.text <- enc2native(rawData()$text)
        tw.text <- tolower(tw.text)
        tw.text <- removeWords(tw.text,c(stopwords('en'),'rt'))
        tw.text <- removePunctuation(tw.text,TRUE)
        tw.text <- unlist(strsplit(tw.text,' '))
        word <- sort(table(tw.text),TRUE)
        wordc <- head(word,n=15)
        wordcloud(names(wordc),wordc,random.color=TRUE,colors=rainbow(10),scale=c(5,2),min.freq=1)
      }
  )
})
```