# Twitter in Shiny App - Input text challenge

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and R.

But in an effort to learn by trying, I have tried to read Twitter API combined with **Shiny** using example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056518/shiny-and-twitter-example). However, I am unable to make the **textIinput$text** reactive so when text is entered by user in the shiny app, the **output$distPlot** is generated.

I tried this

```
aga = reactive ({searchTwitter(input$text, n=3200, lang = "en")})
```

but it never work.

I have also checked these other examples on stackoverflow.com - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430171/r-shiny-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double), [2](https://github.com/sandhiyakothandan/Sentiment-Analysis-on-Twitter-Data-with-Shiny-)

Here is my code and I look forward to your help and suggestions.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(dplyr)




# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  ##Retrieve tweets from Twitter

  ## Twitter authentication
  #Connecting to Twitter
  consumer_key <- "xxx"
  consumer_secret <-"xxx"
  access_token <- "xxx"
  access_secret <- "xxx"
  setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,
                      access_secret)

 **# this does not work**

  #aga = reactive ({searchTwitter(input$text, n=3200, lang = "en")}) 

**#this works**
  aga = searchTwitter("@bhp", n=3200, lang = "en") 


  # convert tweets to a data frame
  agadf <- twListToDF(aga) 


  agadf$created<-as.Date(agadf$created)




  #Sentiment Analysis
  require(devtools)
  #install_github("sentiment140", "okugami79", force= TRUE)
  library(sentiment)
  agasentiments <- sentiment(agadf$text)
  table(agasentiments$polarity)

  # sentiment plot
  agasentiments$score <- 0
  agasentiments$score[agasentiments$polarity == "positive"] <- 1
  agasentiments$score[agasentiments$polarity == "negative"] <- -1
  agasentiments$date <- as.Date(agadf$created)
  agaresult <- aggregate(score ~ date, data = agasentiments, sum)
  plot(agaresult, type = "l")


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(agaresult, type = "l")

  })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Real Time Miner Sentiment"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

        textInput("text", "Text:", "text here"),
        submitButton("Submit")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

@zx8754 - wondering if you can help. I struggled to replicate as in this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456341/how-to-get-these-shinyapp-parameters-to-be-reactive-to-input-changes?rq=1)

Comment: Hello - would appreciate any assistance on this issue please